# Why does this SQL query not order by my alias?

Tags: mysql, sql

This SQL SELECT query gives me all the rows I want, but the ORDER BY clause doesn't seem to be playing along with the alias I define.

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(AVG(ratings.rating), 0) AS avgrating,
    users.username,
    content.*
FROM content
LEFT JOIN ratings
    ON ratings.contentid = content.id
LEFT JOIN users
    ON users.id = content.userid
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY
    avgrating DESC,
    id DESC;
```

Instead of ordering by `avgrating` first and `id` second, it only orders by `id`. I looked through the answers to similar questions, but nothing jumped out at me as helpful to my case. Any ideas on how to solve this? Let me know if I should provide more information.

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the result data. Pardon the nonsense placeholder text.

```
avgrating   username    id  title       content category    userid
3.0000      jijoij      11  nuunun      "foo"   0           2
0.0000      jijoij      10  regreg      "foo"   3           2
0.0000      jijoij      9   fefefe      "foo"   3           2
0.0000      testkonto   8   i34jt4jt    "foo"   3           4
0.0000      testkonto   7   oouo        "foo"   3           4
0.0000      testkonto   6   oyouuoouo   "foo"   3           4
5.0000      testkonto   5   oyouuouo    "foo"   3           4
1.0000      testkonto   4   jijijijiji  "foo"   3           4
0.0000      testkonto   3   fgreg       "foo"   3           4
0.0000      testkonto   2   tbtrb       "foo"   3           4
3.6667      jijoij      1   gergj       "foo"   1           2
```

EDIT 2: I've tried specifying `content.id` in the `ORDER BY` clause since that's the one I wanted. Nothing has changed.

Comment: does it work when you `order by` the expression itself instead of the alias? e.g. `order by IFNULL(AVG(ratings.rating), 0) desc, id desc`

Comment: @SlimsGhost That's a good idea, but I just tried it and it does the same thing.

Comment: In that case, can you post the results you currently have, showing the "incorrect" sorting?

Comment: Do you want it grouped by `content.id` and ordered by `content.id`? Because I believe that's what's happening. An ambiguous `id` is referring to the `from` table.

Comment: If I remember correctly you have to use the actual expression, or you could do a `select a, b, exp() as column_name into #temp from` then `select * from #temp order by column_name`

Comment: @SlimsGhost Gotcha, added the result data.

Comment: @Schwern It is `content.id` that I want to `ORDER BY`. Changing it to that doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @Schwern I'm running MySQL Community Server 5.7.11.

Answer (score 1):

[I put this together in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/524f40/1/0) and it revealed the problem.

```
avgrating   username    id  userid
5           joe         1   1
4           joe         2   1
3           joe         3   1
2           jill        5   4
2           jill        6   4
1           bob         4   3
```

It's grouping and ordering by `content.id`. I suspect the OP wanted `users.id`.  The problem is this:

```
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY
    avgrating DESC,
    id DESC;
```

`id` is ambiguous. All those tables (in my schema anyway) have an `id` column. I'm not sure if there's a standard way to resolve it, but MySQL seems to be picking `content.id` because the query is `FROM content`.

The solution is to make the `id` column unambiguous.

```
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY
    avgrating DESC,
    users.id DESC;
```

[Here's the result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/524f40/3/0).

```
avgrating   username    id  userid
4           joe         1   1
2           jill        5   4
1           bob         4   3
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is indeed `content.id` that I want to ORDER BY. I tried specifying it in the ORDER BY clause just now and that didn't change anything.

Comment: @AgBengip Ah. Darn, now I can't get SQLFiddle to reload my schema. :-/

Comment: @AgBengip Have you tried just `ORDER BY avgrating DESC` with no secondary to see if it will at least sort by avgrating?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't sort at all when I do that.